# "Next time I'll bring a book." — Can I use "the next time" here?

Tags: difference, definite-article, time

As far as I know:
"next time" and "the next time" are interchangeable;
"next time" is an informal form of "the next time".

To make sure of it, I've prepared some examples.

---

[oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/next_1):
**(1)** *Next time I'll bring a book*.
my variant:
**(2)** ***The** next time I'll bring a book*.

Is (2) also correct?
Do (1) and (2) mean the same?
If not, then what's the difference between them?

---

[wordreference.com](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/a-question-about-the-article-the.3034545/post-15337196):
**(3)** *I'll bring the book, next time*.
my variant:
**(4)** *I'll bring the book, **the** next time*.

Is (4) also correct?
Do (3) and (4) mean the same?
If not, then what's the difference between them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There’s no difference in meaning, though the version without *the* sounds better.

If we put things in the past, though, it gets very interesting. Consider this intro and the pair of subsequent sentences:

> The new doctor was fine, but he sat in her waiting room for two hours.

1. So he swore he’d bring a book **the** next time.
2. So he swore he’d bring a book next time.

Version 1 suggests that that next time—his second appointment—has already happened, that it too is in the past. Version 2, on the other hand, suggests that his second appointment is yet to come.

Comment: I think your distinction is a *consequence* of the fact that ***next time*** with no article *and* no further qualification (such as ***the** next time **I come***) is inherently more "immediate". Leading to a tendency (no more than that) for us to say *I'll bring a book **next time*** vs *He said he'd bring a book **the next time he came***. But it's only a weak tendency, anyway.

Comment: I don’t know, @FumbleFingers. If bare *next time* were the more immediate, then wouldn’t it be the one to take place sooner? But as I described, it’s the one that’s still in the future, and thus is the more remote.

Comment: But "next time" is *always* in the future! What I mean is there's more "immediacy" to the reference when the speaker himself is referring to the nearest future occasion *like the one **taking place at time of speaking***. If no such occasion is currently taking place, or the reference is being made by someone other than the "primary agent" (the doctor's receptionist, rather than the patient) it's more likely we'll include the article *and* further identification of that future occasion: *Don't forget to wear a mask **the** next time **you come in.***

Comment: I think your inference about the meaning of the definite article in "the next time" is arbitrary.  It need not have happened already; it could simply be planned or merely expected to occur at some point in the future.  "This practice triple books. I'm bringing an Icelandic saga the next time."

Comment: @TimRonsomedevice, it’s certainly far from ironclad. That’s why I phrased my remark in terms of *suggests*. In any event, your example is in the present tense, and I described a curious thing about its use  in speaking about the past.

Comment: Is it also correct to say "_the following time_" instead of "_the next time_" in your example: "_So he swore he’d bring a book the next time_" (which suggests that that next time has already happened) ? Thanks.

Comment: It’s not incorrect, but neither is it idiomatic.